# How to get around copy-pasting passwords?

Tags: clipboard, password-management, password-protection

The password manager KeePassXC supports Auto-Type: When login fields are detected in a browser, then a click on the key symbol fills in the credentials.

[This (German) blog post](https://www.kuketz-blog.de/keepassxc-auto-type-und-browser-add-on-im-alltag-nutzen-passwoerter-teil1/) highly recommends this procedure, because it protects the user from copy-pasting the password via the clipboard. Instead, the password is transferred directly from the password manager to the login.

So if I understand correctly that the clipboard is not a safe place for passwords, then what is the recommended behaviour wherever Auto-Type does not work? For instance, Auto-Type is not available in many Desktop applications.

**Edits:**

- Sorry for not making this clear: My operating system is Linux Mint 20.2, not Windows. However, the answers which address Windows may be of equal help to Windows users in the future.
- Sorry for not making this clear enough: My question was not, "Is the clipboard a safe place", but rather, "What is best practice to not use the clipboard"?

Answer (score 2):

The clipboard is not a safe place for passwords only when your computer
is infected and the virus is monitoring the clipboard.

Frankly speaking, this advice is bunk - if your computer is infected and
under total control by the virus, it's already too late for you.
All your secrets are already known to the hacker,
who may also encrypt all your files, so that only he has them,
to give them back only for ransom.

Conclusion: Your clipboard is as safe as your computer.
Use your computer with caution.

The auto-fill feature is a good tool that simplifies entering
the password, as such it's usually preferred. But it may fail
for some websites, and then there is no choice but to
use the longer-taking copy-paste.

Comment: Also, the clipboard is not safe because if you copy a password to the clipboard and you leave the pc unattended, someone else can paste the password. Also now that Windows offers clipboard history, they can see what you copied. That is a more serious threat than a virus infection.

Comment: @LPChip: If someone has physical access to the computer, he can do anything he wants, including extracting the entire passwords list from KeePass.

Comment: Not necessarily. Usually password manangers, when properly setup are password protected. You must know the master password in order to extract data. But its easy to go behind someone's computer and check their clipboard history in 10 seconds vs going to open the password manager and export an entire list.

Comment: Picking on the clipboard as a risk is typical for administrators that don't understand the larger picture. I know about a very large company making milliards annually that just a couple of weeks ago in a phishing attempt one guy opened the wrong document. The company is not yet fully functional, losing millions per day. Believe me that clipboards are not the problem.

Comment: I know what you're saying, I'm just focussing on the question. You claim storing the password in the clipboard is not going to be a problem if you compare this to viruses, but I claim that it can be on day-to-day usage. A security audit could say this is a problem.

Comment: I also understand what you're saying, but these security measures belong in the twentieth century. Hackers today are going after bigger game, and certainly not waiting for anybody to do a copy-paste.

Comment: I'm not talking about a hacker. I'm talking about a nosey colleague or customer that gains access to a pc.

Comment: This discussion seems to be more on the question whether or not the clipboard is a safe place. However, the question was how I can avoid the clipboard once I believe that it isn't safe. @harrymc states that I should not hesitate to use the clipboard for entering passwords, which is OK in the context of my question. (Doubting my assumptions seems legitimate.) Nevertheless, if someone knows an _actual_ answer to the question, that would still be interesting for me.

Comment: Basically, the answer is that in some cases you don't have a choice. The usual ridiculous protections, like clearing automatically the clipboard after x time, make me think on this question: If your sandwich has fallen on a dirty floor, how fast do you need to snatch it up so it's still safe to eat?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your point of view, the clipboard is not safe at all.  Any running application, malicious or not, can read and write to your Windows clipboard. This means if you copied a password and do nothing else it will stay in your clipboard until the user is logged out.  This can be made even worse by clipboard managers, which can store your clips past reboots.

I am not sure about KeePassXC, but KeePass itself has an option to clear the clipboard contents after a certain amount of time.  I use KeePass for work and we are required to leave that option enabled, so the contents of the clipboard are removed after 5 seconds.

Comment: If a malicious program is running on your computer, the entire company is in danger, not only your passwords. Hackers work hard to get an entry gate into a company, but once they do they own it all.

Comment: @harrymc All I am saying is if get up and leave and your relative sits down, they have access to anything in the clipboard.  Malicious program or not, the clipboard is not safe.

Comment: @Keltari My OS is Linux Mint. I'm sorry for not mentioning this in the first place. However, please leave the Windows-specific part in your answer, as it may help future visitors of the site. // KeePassXC does also offer clearing the clipboard automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to get around the clipboard more often.

1. Go to an entry in the KeePassXC Database and select the tab *Auto-Type*.
2. Under "Window Associations", add a new entry; the title should match the name of the window where you usually have to copy-paste the password ("Thunderbird", for instance).
3. When the password-prompting window is in the front, a keyboard shortcut (in my environment, it is <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>) will open a KeePassXC window where you can grant the password prompt access to the database entry.

I found this in the KeePass documentations a while ago, maybe it helps someone.